# How does play.db.jpa.Model class provide automatically the auto generated Long id field

Tags: jpa, playframework

I was asked to make some changes (and updates) in a database that is used by a web application using play.db.jpa.Model.
I was wondering how does play.db.jpa.Model class provide automatically the auto generated Long id field
I want to insert data independent the web application

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the class for Model, you will see this snippet of code

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long id;
```

The two annotations are responsible for generation of the autonumber. For more detail of how this works, check out the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) for identifier properties.